# Having problems with the properties in my object

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I am having some issues with the properties of my object, I can get and set the properties from all aspects of my project i.e. from a page with an entry bound to IsCancelled (It gets and sets the property) also from another method i.e. IsCancelled = true; but when I want to read the property that has just been changed from a popup page, the page that calls the popup page always gives the default value, and does not see the changes from the popup page.

Note: Edited to make it conform to the rules as stated by Jason.

FolderView ...

```
public partial class FolderView : ContentPage
{

    public FolderView()
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = NetworkBase = new BaseNetWork(GridFolders, btnConnect, lblNet);
    }
}
```

PopupPage

```
public partial class PopupShareDetails : ContentPage
{
    public PopupShareDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModelBase();
    }

}
```

BaseNetWork  Class..

```
class BaseNetWork : ViewModelBase
{
    public BaseNetWork(Grid grid, Image img, Label lbl)
    {
        BaseImages Images = new BaseImages();
        NetworkShares NetWorkData = new NetworkShares();

        img.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer((view) => OpenShares()));
        async void OpenShares()
        {
                    if (ConnectToShares)
                    {
                        if (HasParams())
                        {
                            DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().InitLoadingPage(new LoadingConnectedShares());
                            DelayTime = 2000;
                        } else {
                            DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().InitLoadingPage(new AddConnectionDetails());
                            DelayTime = 20000;
                        }
                    } else {

                        DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().InitLoadingPage(new LoadingAllShares());
                        DelayTime = 2000;
                }
                    DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().ShowLoadingPage();
                    await Task.Delay(DelayTime).ConfigureAwait(true);
                    if (IsCancelled != true)
                    {
                        NetWorkData.DeploySharesToGrid(grid, null, ConnectToShares);
                        DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().HideLoadingPage();
                        IsCancelled = false;
                    };

                    if (IsConnected)
                    {
                        img.Source = Images.GetImages(3);
                        lbl.Text = "Disconnect";
                    };
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The BaseNetWork class derives from my ViewModelBase

Can anyone tell me why this would happen?

Comment: There is really not enough code here to determine what is happening.   It's also confusing that you appear to be using two different names (Cancelled and IsCancelled) for the same thing?  Finally, how are you sharing the VM instance between multiple pages of your project?

Comment: Hi Jason, as I explained in my comment after if (Cancelled != true) // Normally this is the ... IsCancelled property, but added this to show the result as in the picture. I am using a DependencyService to open the popup pages...`                            DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().InitLoadingPage(new LoadingAllShares());
                            DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().ShowLoadingPage();`

Comment: that doesn't answer my question - how are you sharing the instance of the VM?

Comment: I answer your first question" It's also confusing that you appear to be using two different names (Cancelled and IsCancelled) for the same thing? " Maybe your second question is misunderstood ... VM?

Comment: You are most likely using two different instances of your VM.  Since you cannot demonstrate what mechanism you are using to share them, this is the most likely answer.  If you set a property on instance A that will have no impact on instance B.  They are two completely different objects of the same type.

Comment: Ok I understand it a little better, So if I have a button on the MainPage that opens the PopupPage, how would I pass the the existing instance over to that PopupPage?

Comment: Since you have not posted a [MCVE] I can only guess about exactly what you are doing.  But generally you would pass any data necessary to the new page via it's constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, I have been face bound into learning again :-)

Anyway, I actually resolved this buy doing the following, very similar to that of what Lucas Zhang suggested...

Firstly I created a GlobalViewModel class...

```
public static class GlobalViewModel
{
    private static ViewModelBase ObjectBase = new ViewModelBase();

    public static ViewModelBase BaseObject
    {
        get
        {
            return ObjectBase ;
        }
    }
}
```

Then on each page I call it like so...

```
    ViewModelBase BaseObject = GlobalViewModel.BaseObject;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = BaseObject;
    }
```

If I want to call it from a non inherited class object then I can use the following in a method or at the beginning of that class like so...

```
ViewModelBase BaseObject = GlobalViewModel.MainViewModel; var foo = BaseObject.FooBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the current VM to the popup page . Define a  constructor with the param .

```
public partial class PopupShareDetails : ContentPage
{

    BaseNetWork currentVM;

    public PopupShareDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       // BindingContext = new ViewModelBase();
    }

    public PopupShareDetails(BaseNetWork vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = currentVM = vm;
    }


}
```

And init the popup page when you want to open it .

```
var popupPage = new PopupShareDetails(NetworkBase);
// navigation logic
```